# Insert HTML in first part of IF statement

Tags: php, html, if-statement, syntax

Referencing [an answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11493419/758231), you can break out of PHP during an IF statement using the following syntax:

```
<?php if (get_field ('member_only_content')): ?>
    <span>Put HTML here</span>
<?php else: ?>
    <span>Put HTML here</span>
<?php endif;?>
```

What if I only wanted to break out of php and use HTML in the first part of this statement?

```
<?php if (get_field ('member_only_content')): ?>
    <span>Put HTML here</span>
<?php else: ?>
<?php //more php code here ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Is this the only way to achieve it (multiple php tags), or is there another (perhaps tidier) way?

Comment: It's more common to use the standard code block syntax and an `echo` for a single line of html output. // Which, it seems, the referenced answer already showcased. So, what's the question really?

Comment: `<?php else { echo "Hello world"; } ?>` or with your syntax, `<?php else: echo "Hello world"; endif; ?> ` - no need to break out of PHP for every line, that would just be a mess :p

Comment: I'm referencing as an example, but my own first code block has a large amount of HTML, whilst the second has a large amount of PHP - echoing would be impractical in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply not close the PHP block:

```
<?php
if (get_field ('member_only_content')):
    echo '<span>Put HTML here</span>';
else:
    foo();
    bar();
    // ... your PHP code
endif;´
?>
```

Using `echo` to output HTML works well if it's just 1-2 rows of simple HTML.

If you're going to output a more complex HTML structure or more rows, then I would recommend closing the PHP block, write HTML and then open the PHP block again:

```
<?php
if (get_field ('member_only_content')):
?>

    <span>Here be some complex HTML</span>
    ...

<?php
else:
    foo();
    bar();
    // ... your PHP code
endif;´
?>
```

Comment: The second suggestion is exactly what I was looking for. I was under the (mistaken) impression that I had to close the php tag when using `else:`

Comment: @RyanGillies - Glad I could help. Please accept the answer if it solved your issue so others know that the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
if (get_field ('member_only_content'))
    echo '<span>Put HTML here</span>';
?>
```

if there is only one statement in if block, you can skip the else part.

Comment: That's not the question being asked though. He's asking how he can do his `else` block more tidy since there's no escaping out of PHP to output HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add PHP tags for each line.

There is the other way:

```
<?php
First line code
Second line code
...
?>
```

Only one tag is necessary